# Implemented MaxMin using recursion got recursion limit exceeded error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Implemented max min using divide and conquer. Here is the code

```
#Min-max
INF=float('inf')
def MaxMin(a,i,j,max,min):
    if(i==j):
        min,max=a[i],a[i]
        return max,min
    elif(i==(j-1)):
        print(max,min)
        if(a[i]<a[j]):
            max,min=a[j],a[i]
            return max,min
        else:
            max,min=a[i],a[j]
            return max,min
    else:
        mid=(i+j)/2
        max,min=MaxMin(a,i,mid,max,min)
        max1,min1=MaxMin(a,mid+1,j,max,min)
        if(max<max1):
            max=max1
        if(min>min1):
            min=min1
a=[-7,6,1,-44,44,4,27,45,16,100,23]
MaxMin(a,0,len(a)-1,-INF,INF)
print(max,min)
```

What am I doing wrong? The above code is throwing recursion limit exceeded. The recursion function seems to be going wrong somewhere but I cannot make out where. Please help me out

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? Within 30 sec I found your **main** problem

Comment: Why do you use `()` in `if` statements?

Comment: According to how names and binding work in Python, the last 2 parameters of MaxMin are most likely not going to work. Remove them and just let MaxMin return the two final values

Comment: @Attersson I tried that it's still not working, but I'll try again

Comment: @Attersson Nope not working

Comment: That is not the whole problem, just something wrong

Comment: Try setting a higher recursion limit ( https://www.pythoncentral.io/resetting-the-recursion-limit/#:~:text=Python's%20default%20recursion%20limit%20is,exactly%20make%20for%20lightweight%20code. ) and print some global counter

Comment: @Attersson I have tried setting a higher recursion limit, it still throws the same error

Comment: Log every iteration and a depth counter